# pip install raises raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to do  pip2.7 install -r req.txt in my virtual environmen.

made a virtual environment

`virtualenv -p python venv22`

activated it

`source venv22/bin/activate`

then did

`sudo pip2.7 install -r req.txt`

Tried to install package via pip install but after installing it showed that the modules were not found.

So I tried with pip2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 809, in unpack_url
    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 715, in unpack_file_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 484, in unzip_file
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfp, allowZip64=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 811, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command
```

EDIT:
The req.txt is as [here](https://pastebin.com/MVMpPa25)

[on running pip install -r req.txt](https://pastebin.com/P693watr)

Comment: Why did you use `sudo`?

Comment: my requirements.txt file https://pastebin.com/MVMpPa25

Comment: @DanielRoseman was following this issue which seemed similar https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x/issues/290